# How to make where do the error message show in jquery.validate?

Tags: jquery-validate

How to make where do the error message show in jquery.validate??

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the documentation here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

You define the .error style and jQuery creates the element as needed (as the next sibling to the input field) on validate.

Here is their sample style:

```
label.error { float: none; color: red; padding-left: .5em; vertical-align: top; }
```

And here is an example of an element created on error:

```
<label for="cname" generated="true" class="error">Please enter at least 2 characters.</label>
```